# Does Linux allow process group ids to be reassigned to processes?

Tags: c, linux, posix, job-control, process-group

Suppose pid `X` is a process group leader and `X` terminates, but other processes in the process group remain running (with `X` as their pgid). Will Linux prevent the value `X` from being assigned as a pid to a new process?

I ask this because of a failure condition POSIX allows for `setsid`:

> [EPERM] The calling process is already a process group leader, **or the process group ID of a process other than the calling process matches the process ID of the calling process.**

This error seems to be an unrecoverable condition for code using process groups (i.e. shells) that would be triggered "at random", making it even more odious. I would assume any implementation aiming at sane levels of quality would avoid reassigning `X` as a pid while it's still in use as a pgid, but I can't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: Close voter, care to explain how knowing the behavior and possible error cases for an implementation is not relevant to programming for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a problem, because [fork guarantees](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> The child process ID also shall not match any active process group ID.

And `fork` is the only way to create new processes.

Comment: This seems to settle it. Any idea why that bogus language was put in the specification for `setsid` if it can never apply?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `fork` is not the only way to create new processes. There's `posix_spawn`, `posix_spawnp`, `popen`, and `system` too.

Comment: Oh, and I figured out why the "bogus" language is in the specification. It's not bogus. If the process calling `setsid` is a process group **leader**, then other processes in its process group will have its process id as their process group id. In this case, `setsid` must be forbidden because a new session needs a new session id and process group id, which would be equal to the caller's pid. But this id cannot be used as a new process group id because a process group with that id already exists. BTW, this is the reason `daemon(3)` traditionally double-`fork`s.

Comment: @R: Sorry, but I don't get it. The spec says `EPERM` happens if (1) "the calling process is already a process group leader" **or** (2) "the process group ID of a process other than the calling process matches the process ID of the calling process". Your explanation makes sense for (1), but (2) still looks redundant/impossible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Nemo is correct that POSIX guarantees that `fork()` will not re-use an existing PGID as a PID; however, there is more to the story.

Process groups, and process group leaders, can also be changed using [`setpgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html#).  The following example code causes the existence of a process group equal to the PID of the current process, which the current process is not in:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pgrp_orig;
    pid_t child;
    int status;

    /* Fork so that we are not a process group leader */
    if (fork()) {
        /* Grandparent process */
        wait(&status);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Record our original process group, then start a new one */
    pgrp_orig = getpgrp();
    if (setpgid(0, 0))
        perror("setpgid");

    child = fork();

    if (!child) {
        /* Child process */
        pause();
        return 0;
    }

    /* Switch back to original process group.  Child remains in the new one */
    if (setpgid(0, pgrp_orig))
        perror("setpgid");

    printf("Parent pid=%ld, pgid=%ld\n", (long)getpid(), (long)getpgrp());
    printf("Child pid=%ld, pgid=%ld\n", (long)child, (long)getpgid(child));

    /* Wake child up to finish up */
    kill(child, SIGUSR1);
    wait(&status);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if the parent process tries to call `setsid()` here before the child exits, the failure condition you asked about will be triggered.

However, due to the restrictions on the allowable transitions that `setpgid()` can cause, this can't cause the kind of random failures you're worried about.  The breakage is confined to a single session.

Comment: In particular, `setsid` cannot fail for this reason if called immediately after `fork` in the child process, right?

Comment: @R.: That *is* possible, but only if the parent process mucks about to deliberately cause it (after the fork, the parent uses `setpgid()` to put the child into its own process group, then uses `setpgid()` to put another process into that process group too, then uses `setpgid()` a third time to put the child back into its original process group).  Obviously it's racy too.